# Subject operator does not provide the correct answers

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

Would you please let me know why the total summation in the below posted code is 14?? I expected it to be 10

I was reading a tutorial about using rx in java 8. But i want to make sure that the totsl summation is as expected.

Please have a look at the below code:

**code**:

```
Integer subscriber1 = 0;
Integer subscriber2 = 0;
Observer<Integer> getFirstObserver() {
return new Observer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer value) {
       subscriber1 += value;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("Subscriber1 completed");
    }
};
}

Observer<Integer> getSecondObserver() {
 return new Observer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer value) {
        subscriber2 += value;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("Subscriber2 completed");
    }
};
}

PublishSubject<Integer> subject = 
PublishSubject.create(); 
subject.subscribe(getFirstObserver()); 
subject.onNext(1); 
subject.onNext(2); 
subject.onNext(3); 
subject.subscribe(getSecondObserver()); 
subject.onNext(4); 
 subject.onCompleted();

 assertTrue(subscriber1 + subscriber2 == 14)
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code with breakpoints?

Comment: Have you checked what the values of your variables are at the end of your program?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be 10? The first subscriber receives 1, 2, 3 and 4, giving a total of 10 for the first subscriber. The second subscriber receives 4, giving a total of 4 for the second subscriber. Adding 10 and 4 gives 14 for both subscribers together.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it step by step.

When subscribe first observer `subject.subscribe(getFirstObserver());`
 and post `1`,`2`,`3` - after that your `subscriber1 = 6`. Then you subscibe second observer `subject.subscribe(getSecondObserver());` (but don't unsubscribe first one, so first observer will receive events) and post `4` - after that `subscriber1 = 10` and `subscriber2 = 4`. So you result will be `14`.

If you wan't disable your first observer after subscribing new, you should save `Disposable` returned by `subject.subscribe(getFirstObserver());` and dispose it before subsribing new observer.

Comment: Would you please let me know how to use disposable in the example provided

Comment: According to documentation http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe--, `subscribe` method return `Disposable` instance. Until you invoke `disposable.dispose()` or `onCompleted()|onError()` of `publishSubject` happen,  you observer will be active.